# How to host a java webapplication using Amazon Cloud engine?

Tags: java, web, host

We have a java web application to be hosted in internet. We heard that amazon cloud engine is good for that. Is there any idea to host that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't very precise, but I guess you want to use Amazon Web Service to deploy and host a `war` containing your application?

If so, look at the docs [here](http://aws.amazon.com/application-hosting/), they'll get you started on how to do that.

Having used their EC2 service as a total newbie I can tell you it is really easy to use to deploy `wars`, snapshot logs and manage different versions of your app.